# Installing Cordova on Mac Mini from Terminal gives error

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, terminal, npm

I am trying to install cordova using Mac Mini Terminal.

The command I am using is as follows

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

I even tried without Sudo. I am connected to internet using Wifi + Lan too.

I tried disabling Wifi and connect and other way round.

I am not on proxy server. I connect to internet using a Wifi Connection which is through WIFI router. I am based in India.

I get following error.( Here is error log. )

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install', '-g', 'cordova' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.32
4 verbose cache add [ 'cordova', null ]
5 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="cordova" args=["cordova",null]
6 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
6 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
6 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
6 verbose parsed url   host: null,
6 verbose parsed url   port: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
6 verbose parsed url   search: null,
6 verbose parsed url   query: null,
6 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'cordova',
6 verbose parsed url   path: 'cordova',
6 verbose parsed url   href: 'cordova' }
7 silly lockFile a98f2055-cordova cordova
8 verbose lock cordova /Users/vilas_den/.npm/a98f2055-cordova.lock
9 silly lockFile a98f2055-cordova cordova 10 silly lockFile a98f2055-cordova cordova
11 verbose addNamed [ 'cordova', '' ]
12 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
13 silly lockFile de8d9fad-cordova cordova@
14 verbose lock cordova@ /Users/vilas_den/.npm/de8d9fad-cordova.lock
15 silly addNameRange { name: 'cordova', range: '*', hasData: false }
16 verbose request where is /cordova
17 verbose request registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
18 verbose request id b73a5f8f40fd1d7c
19 verbose url raw /cordova
20 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './cordova' ]
21 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
22 verbose request where is https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
23 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 16:31:28
24 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
26 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 16:31:39
27 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
28 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
29 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 16:32:39 30 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
31 silly lockFile de8d9fad-cordova cordova@
32 silly lockFile de8d9fad-cordova cordova@
33 error network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
33 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
33 error network and is related to network connectivity.
33 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
33 error network
33 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
33 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
34 error System Darwin 13.3.0
35 error command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
36 error cwd /Users/vilas_den
37 error node -v v0.10.32
38 error npm -v 1.4.28
39 error syscall getaddrinfo
40 error code ENOTFOUND
41 error errno ENOTFOUND
42 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

So please let me know.

Comment: Looks like your DNS server can't resolve registry.npmjs.org.

Comment: Check that your DNS settings are ok, for example by opening the URL (https://registry.npmjs.org/) in a browser on the same machine. If that works, you probably need to flush some DNS cache (although I can't remember straight off how to do it on MacOS)

Comment: I did Flushing of DNS but still not able to install the plugin

Comment: also I am able to ping to registry.npmjs.org

Comment: Any Mac Wiz who can help here?